# Не вставляется картина в background

Tags: html, css

Проблема с установкой фонового изображения в блок

html:`<div class="block-slider"> <div class="row slider-row"> d </div> </div>`

css:`.block-slider{ background: url("src/img/background-block.svg"); height:465px; }`

Comment: Скорее всего путь к картинке неправильный. Проверьте

Comment: Вот так делается шаг назад:../src/img/background-block.svg?

Comment: Да, но я не знаю где ваш файл. Может он не на уровень выше)

Answer (score 0):

все нормально должно быть
проверьте у себя

1. верность пути к картинке
2. размер картинки (возможно она настолько большая, что вы ее не видите) - в текущем примере если убрать `background-soze: cover;` вы увидите к чему это приводит

вот пример:

```css
.block {
    width:  200px;
    height: 150px;
    
    border: 3px solid darkorange;
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    background: url("https://svgsilh.com/svg/1801287.svg");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'block'>
</div>
```